# How to add a dependency manually in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, pom.xml

I am trying to add a .pom file to eclipse with some dependencies and I cannot understand how. The .pom is https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/glxn/qrgen/javase/2.0/javase-2.0.pom. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can type the XML in the POM or you can use the "Maven -> Add Dependency" function of the context menu. You would have to specify the repository coordinates like

```
net.glxn.qrgen:javase:2.0
```

Eclipse tells me however, it is a JAR dependency, not of packaging type POM.

[image: Eclipse Add Dependency Screenshot]

Results in:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.glxn.qrgen</groupId>
    <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It does not allow me to type into the XML for some reason. Any tips?

Comment: (You mean your project pom, not the display of the dependency, right? the dependency is read only). Do you have installed the m2e plugin? Is it an XML editor with a tree like outline or a text editor? If m2e is currectly installed it will actually have tabs at the bottom where you can see a form and a source view (and not the tree and source vie from normal xml editor). Maybe the default editor is wron. Right-click the pom.xml and use "Open With -> Maven POM Editor".